# counting non-empty lines and sum of lengths of those lines in python

Tags: function, python-3.x, tuples, lambda

Am trying to create a function that takes a filename and it returns a 2-tuple with the number of the non-empty lines in that program, and the sum of the lengths of all those lines. Here is my current program:

```
def code_metric(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f: 
        lines = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.strip(), f)))
        num_chars = sum(map(lambda l: len(re.sub('\s', '', l)), f))

    return(lines, num_chars)
```

The result I get is get if I do:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
print(code_metric('cmtest.py'))
```

is

```
(3, 0)
```

when it should be:

```
(3,85)
```

Also is there a better way of finding the sum of the length of lines using using the functionals map, filter, and reduce? I did it for the first part but couldn't figure out the second half. AM kinda new to python so any help would be great.

Here is the test file called cmtest.py:

```
import prompt,math

x = prompt.for_int('Enter x')
print(x,'!=',math.factorial(x),sep='')

First line has 18 characters (including white space)
Second line has 29 characters
Third line has 38 characters

[(1, 18), (1, 29), (1, 38)]
```

The line count is 85 characters including white spaces. I apologize, I mis-read the problem. The length total for each line should include the whitespaces as well.

Comment: Are you sure when you counted the number of characters you didn't count the spaces in the lines?

Comment: You're doing two iterations (and each time you're opening the file and looping over the lines) -if you want to increase efficiency, why not combine both actions into one iteration?

Comment: @Aradmey- Am fairly sure of that. It's only off by 1. That's why I can't seem to figure out why? I

Comment: @alfasin- Am not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions as to how to do it?

Comment: You're counting all characters which aren't the space character.  So if there's some whitespace you're not seeing -- a tab or an extra CR at the end -- your count might not be what you expect.  After `for line in f:`, you can add `print(repr(line))` to see what's really there.  (PS: you might be interested in the `isspace` method.)

Comment: @DSM- I need the sum of characters in the file excluding any white space/empty lines in the beginning, middle or the end.

Comment: @DSM- This is what am seeing after the `print(repr(line))`:           `'import prompt,math\n'
'\n'
"x = prompt.for_int('Enter x')\n"
"print(x,'!=',math.factorial(x),sep='')"`

Comment: The issue you have now is that ```lines = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.strip(), f)))``` reads the entire file and ```num_chars = sum(map(lambda l: len(re.sub('\s', '', l)), f))```has nothing left to process. You can either call f.seek(0) between the two lines or reopen the file.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida- I've updated the question . Am sorry I mis-read the question myself. The length of each line and the sum should include the white spaces as well. Sorry about that. Is there a way to do both without re-opening the file again?

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS do you *have* to use... `filter` and `lamba`s - seems a bit OTT for what could be done simpler...

Comment: @JonClements- Yes, I do have to use lambda, filter and map. Its for learning purposes only.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simple approach is to build a generator to strip trailing whitespace, then `enumerate` over that (with a start value of 1) `filter`ing out blank lines, and summing the length of each line in turn, eg:

```
def code_metric(filename):
    line_count = char_count = 0
    with open(filename) as fin:
        stripped = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
        for line_count, line in enumerate(filter(None, stripped), 1):
            char_count += len(line)
    return line_count, char_count

print(code_metric('cmtest.py'))
# (3, 85)
```

Comment: I understand but It must be implemented using the functional programming style, using the functionals map, filter, and reduce. It's for learning purposes.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS do-able - albeit not highly readable/recommended... gimme a mo' :p

Comment: @JonClements- any luck in figuring it out??

Answer (score 1):

In order to count lines, maybe this code is cleaner:

```
with open(file) as f:
    lines = len(file.readlines())
```

For the second part of your program, if you intend to count only non-empty characters, then you forgot to remove '\t' and '\n'. If that's the case

```
with open(file) as f:
    num_chars = len(re.sub('\s', '', f.read()))
```

Some people have advised you to do both things in one loop. That is fine, but if you keep them separated you can make them into different functions and have more reusability of them that way. Unless you are handling huge files (or executing this coded millions of times), it shouldn't matter in terms of performance.

Comment: If I use `with open(file) as f:
    num_chars = sum(map(lambda l: len(re.sub('\s', '', l)), f))` I get `(3,0)` instead of `(3,85)`

Comment: How do your lines look like? I have a file with lines ```abc d a e``` and ```f oo o    ```. After running that I get ```num_chars``` equals to 10.

Comment: Almeda- There is a test file in the question. That's the file am testing and the lines look exactly as shown in the example.

Comment: The number of non-empty characters on that file is actually 200. That's what that line returns. I changed it to something nicer that I have just realised now, though.

Comment: Still returns `(3,0)`

Comment: I think I'd need to see how you added that line to your code. If you run only those two lines (assigning file to "cmtest.py" and importing re) on your interactive interpreter you'll see num_chars being assigned properly. I manually counted it and the correct answer is 81 (I said 200 before because I was using the wrong file :P)