# Counting non blank and sum of length of lines in python

Tags: function, python-3.x, functional-programming, tuples

Am trying to create a function that takes a filename and it returns a 2-tuple with the number of the non-empty lines in that program, and the sum of the lengths of all those lines. Here is my current program. I made an attempy and got the following code:

```
def code_metric(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    char_count = sum(map(len,(map(str.strip,filter(None,lines)))))
    return len(lines), char_count
```

Am supposed to use the functionals map, filter, and reduce for this. I had asked the question previously and improved on my answer but its still giving me an  error. Here is the link to the previous version of the question:

[Old program code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388432/counting-non-empty-lines-and-sum-of-lengths-of-those-lines-in-python/28390075?noredirect=1#comment45117718_28390075)

When I run the file cmtest.py which has the following content

```
import prompt,math

x = prompt.for_int('Enter x')
print(x,'!=',math.factorial(x),sep='')
```

the result should be

```
(3,85)
```

but I keep getting:

```
(4,85)
```

Another file colltaz.py to be tested for example:

the result should be:

```
(73, 2856)
```

bit I keep getting:

```
(59, 2796)
```

Here is a link to the collatz.py file:

[Collatz.py file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12K4C_ZJog4Q3k5LVdPOXFoaWM/view?usp=sharing)
Can anyone help me with correcting the code. Am fairly new to python and any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def code_metric(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    nonblanklines = [line for line in lines if line]
    return len(nonblanklines), sum(len(line) for line in nonblanklines)
```

Examples:

```
>>> code_metric('collatz.py')
(73, 2856)

>>> code_metric('cmtest.py')
(3, 85)
```

#### Discussion

I was able to achieve the desired result for `collatz.py` only by removing the trailing newline and trailing blanks off the end of the lines.  That is done in this step:

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

The next step is to remove the blank lines:

```
nonblanklines = [line for line in lines if line]
```

We want to return the number of non-blank lines:

```
len(nonblanklines)
```

We also want to return the total number of characters on the non-blank lines:

```
sum(len(line) for line in nonblanklines)
```

#### Alternate Version for Large Files

This version does not require keeping the file in memory all at once:

```
def code_metric2(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lengths = [len(line) for line in (line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()) if line]
    return len(lengths), sum(lengths)
```

#### Alternate Version Using `reduce`

Python's createor, Guido van Rossum, [wrote this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) about the `reduce` builtin:

> So now reduce(). This is actually the one I've always hated most,
>   because, apart from a few examples involving + or *, almost every time
>   I see a reduce() call with a non-trivial function argument, I need to
>   grab pen and paper to diagram what's actually being fed into that
>   function before I understand what the reduce() is supposed to do. So
>   in my mind, the applicability of reduce() is pretty much limited to
>   associative operators, and in all other cases it's better to write out
>   the accumulation loop explicitly.

Accordingly `reduce` is [no longer a builtin in python3](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/587).  For compatibility, though, it remains available in the `functools` module.  The code below how `reduce` can be used for this particular problem:

```
from functools import reduce

def code_metric3(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lengths = [len(line) for line in (line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()) if line]
    return len(lengths), reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, lengths)
```

Here is yet another version which makes heavier use of `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
def code_metric4(file_name):
    def fn(prior, line):
        nlines, length = prior
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            nlines += 1
            length += len(line)
        return nlines, length
    with open(file_name) as f:
        nlines, length = reduce(fn, f.readlines(), (0, 0))
    return nlines, length
```

Comment: @John1024- Thanks..It seems to work for that particular file but not any other file. It keeps giving me wrong results.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS Please give me an example of such a file along with (a) the output that you get and (b) the output that you think you should get.

Comment: @John1024- have updated the question and attached a link to the file with the actual and expected output.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS After some tests, the trick seems to be to remove both the trailing newline and any trailing blanks from the lines before doing the counting.  I have updated the answer with code that works for both examples.

Comment: @John1024- Thanks. Is there a way to do the same operation using `reduce` as well?

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS I added a section that shows how to use `reduce`.  It also discusses the current status of `reduce` in python3.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS I added another example of a more advanced use of `reduce`.